# Is there a relation between self-intersection and covering map?

Tags: algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds, covering-spaces, intersection-theory, 4-manifolds

Let $X$ and $Y$ be compact oriented smooth 4-manifolds. There is a well-defined intersection form $H_2(X)\times H_2(X)\to \Bbb Z$, $(\alpha,\beta)\mapsto \alpha \cdot \beta$, and similarly for $Y$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_form_of_a_4-manifold).

Suppose $f:X\to Y$ is an $n$-fold covering map. For a homology class $\alpha\in H_2(X)$, is there a relation between the self intersection $\alpha^2=\alpha \cdot \alpha$ and $(f_*\alpha)^2$? The reason I am interested in this problem is that I think it may help the question: [Intersection of two lines in weighted projective plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4296464/intersection-of-two-lines-in-weighted-projective-plane).

Any related comments will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think there really is one in the pushforward direction (non-intersecting classes might intersect in the image since they're from different sheets), but $|\alpha^2|\leq |f_*\alpha|^2$ seems true.  There's a pullback version using the cohomology formulation of the intersection form, but all it does is multiply by $n$.

Comment: @KyleMiller Do you mean $(\alpha)^2 = n\cdot (f^*\alpha)^2$ in cohomology?

Comment: $(f^*\alpha)^2=\langle f^*\alpha\smile f^*\alpha,[X]\rangle = \langle\alpha\smile\alpha,f_*[X]\rangle = n\langle \alpha\smile\alpha,[Y]\rangle = n(\alpha)^2$

Comment: I think, it is really a wasted bounty. As Kyle explained, the natural relation is for the pull-back, not for push-forward. You cannot really predict the self-intersection of the push-forward in terms of the original self-intersection. For instance, you can have $\alpha \cdot \alpha=0$ but $f_*(\alpha)\cdot f_*(\alpha)\ne 0$.